# Cordova plugins undefined

Tags: javascript, cordova, cordova-plugins

I am trying to use the ZeroConf plugin for Cordova.
I never used any Cordova plugin before.

These are the steps I did :

```
cordova create myApp
cordova platform add android
cordova platform add ios
cordova platform add browser
cordova plugins add https://github.com/cambiocreative/cordova-plugin-zeroconf
```

Afterwards, I changed the default `onDeviceReady` function so that "index.js" file (in the `myApp/www/` directory) looks as follow :

```
var app = {
    ...

    onDeviceReady: function() {
        app.receivedEvent('deviceready');

        if(cordova && cordova.plugins) {
            console.log('cordova.plugins is available');
        } else {
            console.log('cordova.plugins NOT available');
        }
    },

    ...
};

app.initialize();
```

Unfortunately it always logs "cordova.plugins NOT available". I first checked if `cordova` exists and it does, however, `cordova.plugins` is undefined. Note that i'm testing this in the browser (`cordova run browser`) to find the problem, once `cordova.plugins` won't be undefined anymore I will be able to use the ZeroConf plugin.

I searched for hours, read a lot of similar topics but none could help for me.

What I tried :

- `cordova plugin ls` --> ZeroConf plugin is present `com.cambiocreative.cordova.plugin.zeroconf 1.0.9 "Cordova ZeroConf Plugin"`
- Verified that `index.html` loads the `cordova.js` script
- I edited the `config.xml` file (in `myApp/www/config.xml`) and added `<plugin name="com.cambiocreative.cordova.plugin.zeroconf" version="1" />` , but that did not helped. Also tried `<feature name="ZeroConf"><param name="android-package" value="com.cambiocreative.cordova.plugin.ZeroConf" /><param name="onload" value="true" /></feature>` without success.

This is the order in which i include the scripts in `index.html` (in `myApp/www/index.html`) :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
```

EDIT : I tried accessing the `ZeroConf` object directly from the "zeroconf.js" file, without success.

I edited `onDeviceReady` function :

```
onDeviceReady: function() {
    app.receivedEvent('deviceready');

    var el = document.getElementById("zcOK");

    if(typeof ZeroConf !== 'undefined') {
        el.innerHTML = "ZEROCONF READY";
    } else {
        el.innerHTML = "ZEROCONF NOT READY";
    } 
}
```

But this displays "ZEROCONF NOT READY"...

This is how my index now look like (i only added a paragraph with `id="zcOK"` to display the above).

```
<p id="zcOK">ZeroConf test</p>
<!-- ORDER IN WHICH THE SCRIPTS ARE LOADED -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../plugins/com.cambiocreative.cordova.plugin.zeroconf/www/zeroconf.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script> <!-- Contains the onDeviceReady function -->
```

However, now I don't know if "ZeroConf" is undefined because there is some problem with the plugin or because it would not be accessible from within "index.js" because it was included in "index.html" ?

Comment: cordova plugins do not work in the browser; you have to test them on device or in the device simulator.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Thanks, I was supposing something like that. However, I did the test in an iPhone simulator too (by running the xcode project made by cordova and displaying the value of `cordova.plugins` but there too it is `undefined`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Examining the [config.xml](https://github.com/cambiocreative/cordova-plugin-zeroconf/blob/master/plugin.xml) and the [JS file](https://github.com/cambiocreative/cordova-plugin-zeroconf/blob/master/www/zeroconf.js) of cordova-plugin-zeroconf I found this declaration:

```
<js-module src="www/zeroconf.js" name="ZeroConf">
    <clobbers target="cambiocreative.CDVZeroConfig" />
</js-module>
```

So the plugin API should be available at this name space: **cambiocreative.CDVZeroConfig**

In fact as of [Cordova Plugins documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/plugin_ref/spec.html#js-module-element):

> ... tags are allowed within `<js-module>`:
>
> `<clobbers target="some.value"/>` indicates that the module.exports is
>   inserted into the window object as `window.some.value`. You can have as
>   many `<clobbers>` as you like. Any object not available on window is
>   created.
>   ...

Comment: Would you have any clue why calling `cambiocreative.CDVZeroConfig.register(...);` gives me following error in the console? `HelloCordova[14770:2190065] ERROR: Method 'register:' not defined in Plugin 'ZeroConf'`. I listed all methods of `cambiocreative.CDVZeroConfig` and it does contain the register field (method) ... I think it has something to do with the "zeroconf.js" file which does e.g. `return exec(success, failure, "ZeroConf", "list", [type, timeout]);` and ZeroConf not being the right name anymore or something like that?

Comment: I've seen that there are several repositories for that plugin (another is https://github.com/vstirbu/ZeroConf/): the definitions in the JS are the same. The reference to ZeroConf object (internally to the zeroconf.js) appear correct. Unfortunatly I don't know this plugin and its purpose. Maybe if you share a piece of code I could try...

Comment: I currently have just one or two calls to methods of the plugin. (One call to publish a service (using `register` function) and another to list al services that match a given tag (using `list` function). Here you can find the project, the files containing those calls are `index.js` and `test.js`. In the meantime i will also search what could be the problem. https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0BzEb6HZK4RZZc2FiTE44LVUxRjQ&usp=sharing

Comment: What i find strange is that it says that the method "register:" is not defined, but why is there that ":" ? I looked in the `zeroconf.js` file and it calls cordova exec like this `exec(null, ZeroConf.fail, "ZeroConf", "register", [type, name, port, text]);` so I don't understand where that ":" comes from, maybe it's that that causes the problem?

Comment: I've done several tests with no success :(. Here is a folder with some edits to your original cordova project https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B1hy5jkvdozoUTl5cUs1VGdvdzA&usp=sharing. I've added also my android logs...

Comment: I've seen also this [issue](https://github.com/vstirbu/ZeroConf/issues/14) and so tried to update jmdns.jar with no success; added bluetooth permission... I don't know sufficiently the matter to do more, sorry :(

Comment: Thanks a lot for your efforts and time! I tried to install a similar plugin, and magically that one works :) Here it is https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-zeroconf

Answer (score 2):

Probably the plugins that you are including dont use the cordova.plugin window. Just try to call the plugin functions, and check if they work.

Comment: Thanks for your help! How can i call a plugin directly? I tried including the "zeroconf.js" script directly in the index but that did not work.

Comment: @HyperZ Have you tried to check directly the global ZeroConf object?

Comment: @beaver I realized this some minutes ago, i'm now testing it :) I'll keep you in touch.

Comment: @beaver I extensively tested multiple things but it did not work. "ZeroConf" is always undefined.. Note that I edited the post to reflect my changes.

Answer (score 0):

For those who faced `(cordova.plugins === undefined)`, but it's 100% should be.

/src/plugins/plugin_name/plugin.xml
Find tag like this:

```
<js-module src="www/plugin_name.js" name="Plugin_name">
    <clobbers target="cordova.plugins.plugin_name" />
</js-module>
```

/scr/config.xml
If the tag doesn't exist just copy-paste it before `</widget>`